# How to define a procedure type that works for a local procedure?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, subroutine

I'm creating a request queue in a custom thread `TMyThread` and I'm having difficulties defining a procedure type which can be used for a subroutine. I have a record which represents the request, a corresponding record pointer, and a procedure type which is used in the record *and* uses the record pointer...

```
type
  PRequest = ^TRequest;

  TResponseProc = procedure(Sender: TMyThread; Request: PRequest);

  TRequest = record
    Request: String;
    Proc: TResponseProc;
    Response: String;
  end;
```

The problem is, when I implement a subroutine named `ResponseProc` and try to assign `ResponseProc` to a `TResponseProc`, it doesn't work, and the IDE returns this error message:

```
[DCC Error] MyProject.dpr(42): E2094 Local procedure/function 'ResponseProc' assigned to procedure variable
```

How do I define this procedure type `TResponse` and use it with a subroutine?

Comment: The answer to this is available in the XE2 documentation (the local install, not via the docwiki) with a simple search of `E2094`. SO should *not* be considered a replacement for a check of the documentation first. The only reason I'm not downvoting is that the question is well written, but I'm voting to close because it never should have been asked in the first place.

Comment: Oh so useful questions/answers aren't fit for StackOverflow anymore? I've seen plenty of good questions here which could have been discovered in the documentation.

Comment: It's also very awkward that you would vote to close as "Not a real question" because you yourself said it's a well written question.

Comment: Well written does not mean "good". If I post a question here that explains general principals of math which ends up to equating to "What is 12 * 12?", the fact I used good phrasing does not excuse my failure to know basic math, use a pen and paper, or start Windows Calculator. :-) If you prefer, I can downvote as well; I thought I was being nice not to do so.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5044981/loosen-local-procedure-function-assigned-to-procedure-variable-restriction-gra

Comment: Personally I wouldn't have voted to close this, as it's not a trivial thing and finding it the docs would not be easy to do. Comparing this question to "12 * 12" is not fair.

Comment: The answer in the question Sertac links to is a perfect solution to my question, it's more appropriate to have been closed as a duplicate to that question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The record and procedure declarations are fine. The error message indicates that you're using a *local procedure*, which is one that's defined inside the scope of another function. You cannot use pointers to such functions because they require extra work to call, which cannot be expressed in an ordinary function pointer. (The compiler disallows creating pointers to functions that a caller won't know how to use.)

The solution is to move your function *outside* whatever other function you defined it in. If that's hard to do because the inner function uses variables from the outer function, then you'll have to figure out some other way of getting their values to the other function, such as by passing them as parameters, perhaps making them additional members of that request record.

Another option is to use a *procedure reference*, and then define the local procedure as an *anonymous procedure* instead. It can access local variables, although only Delphi and C++ Builder will know how to invoke it, so it's not an option if you need external API compatibility.

Comment: I read back to this question/answer and was starting to think to myself "The guy asking this question had no clue what he was doing." Then I realized that was myself.